# How do I edit WCF Data Service objects with ASP.NET MVC 2?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-2, wcf-data-services

I don't want to put any more code into my controller than I have to.

This **works:**

```
    //
    // POST: /Duty/Edit/5

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(Duty Model)
    {
        Duty Attached = (from Duty d in ctx.Duties
                         where d.Id == Model.Id
                         select d).Single();
        Attached.Designation = Model.Designation;
        Attached.Instruction = Model.Instruction;
        Attached.OccasionId = Model.OccasionId;
        Attached.Summary = Model.Summary;
        ctx.UpdateObject(Attached);
        ctx.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

But, I don't want to have to type every property.

This **fails:**

```
    //
    // POST: /Duty/Edit/5

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(Duty Model)
    {
        ctx.AttachTo("Duty", Model);
        ctx.UpdateObject(Model);
        ctx.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

It throws a **System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceClientException:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<error xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata">
  <code></code>
  <message xml:lang="en-US">Resource not found for the segment 'Duty'.</message>
</error>
```

**Why?** How *should* I write this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guessing from your code the entity set is actually called "Duties". So your code should look like:
    // 
    // POST: /Duty/Edit/5

```
[HttpPost] 
public ActionResult Edit(Duty Model) 
{ 
    ctx.AttachTo("Duties", Model); 
    ctx.UpdateObject(Model); 
    ctx.SaveChanges(); 
    return RedirectToAction("Index"); 
}
```

(The first parameter for the AttachTo method is the entity set name, not the name of the entity type.)
Note that in order for this to work, you must be sure that the entity in question already exists on the server (that is entity with the same key property values). This will issue a PUT request to that entity, and if it doesn't exist it will fail with 404.

Answer (score 1):

try this it might work:

```
ctx.AttachUpdated(Model);
ctx.SaveChanges();
```

This will tell data context that every property has been updated.

Comment: '...Entities' does not contain a definition for 'AttachUpdated' and no extension method 'AttachUpdated' accepting a first argument of type '...Entities' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)